# Regular Expression - how do I tighten this up?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following statement:

```
if (new RegExp("\\b" + product.toLowerCase() + "\\b").test(cellVal.toLowerCase())) {
    console.log(product.toLowerCase() + " : " + cellVal.toLowerCase());
}
```

I'm having an issue with products that are similar.  I have the following products that are causing an issue:

1. tpd
2. tpd - activity

What I'm finding is that the `test` statement is passing as true when tpd or tpd - activity is passed in and tested against each other.

What I would like is if tpd is found as a whole word then the test should pass.  If tpd - activity is found then that should pass.  But what is happening is that tpd is also picking up a match in tpd - activity.  I thought the `\\b` would account for this scenario.

`product` is coming from a database list and both products are valid.  `cellVal` is the text from an HTML table.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any extra text in `cellVal` or is it only going to be `tpd` or `tpd - activity` (well, among the other values).

Comment: @vlaz - there is some variation in the cellVal (especially in the tpd - activity, I've seen it where it has tpd - activity base as well) - however if it finds tpd -activity then it needs to match on that.

Comment: Replace both `\\b` tokens with `^` and `$` respectively: `new RegExp("^" + product.toLowerCase() + "$")`

Comment: You're regex just test if the word `product` is present in the `cellValue` and `"tpd - activity"` contains `"tpd"`. `\b` just checks for a word boundary (space, punctuation, etc.)

Comment: @revo - That looks like that cleared up my issue.  If you want to add your answer I will accept it.

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but if adding `^$` fixes your problem, then you don't need regex at all. A simple string compare is all you need: `if ( product.toLowerCase() == cellVal.toLowerCase() )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using word boundaries you can assert boundaries around words not an entire input string. For matching against whole string you need `^` (caret - beginning of input string) and `$` (dollar - end of input string) anchors:

```
new RegExp("^" + product.toLowerCase() + "$")
```

Comment: You can use the `i` flag instead of all those `toLowerCase()` calls.

Comment: This should be a comment under question itself.

Comment: @revo - Thanks, this helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sort the products backwards after length:

```
const products = ["tpd - activity", "tpd"];
```

(If you actually need to sort them programmatically):

```
products.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
```

Then get the first included:

```
const result = products.find(p => cellVal.toLowerCase().includes(p));

console.log(result);
```